# find the record with the matching multiple objects from sub array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

**Data Stored in DB:**
How to get the record with the matching multiple objects of subarrays **sub_question**

```json
{
    "_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d2f",
    "title": "Searching Relevant Cases",
    "question": "Your Industry",
    "vendor_id": "61b8324040fb21d80f3e6702",
    "answer_type": "is_radio",
    "optional_answer": false,
    "sub_question_type": "none",
    "answers": [
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d30",
            "answer": "Bank"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d31",
            "answer": "Tech"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d32",
            "answer": "Other"
        }
    ],
    "view": "list_view",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_delete": false,
    "sub_question": [],
    "draggable_list": [],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d45",
    "title": "Searching Relevant Cases",
    "question": "Employee size",
    "vendor_id": "61b8324040fb21d80f3e6702",
    "answer_type": "is_radio",
    "optional_answer": false,
    "sub_question_type": "none",
    "answers": [
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d46",
            "answer": "SMB (<100)"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d47",
            "answer": "Mid (100 - 1000)"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d48",
            "answer": "Enterprise (> 1000)"
        }
    ],
    "view": "list_view",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_delete": false,
    "sub_question": [],
    "draggable_list": [],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d5e",
    "title": "Dependent",
    "question": "On previous Chosen option",
    "vendor_id": "61b8324040fb21d80f3e6702",
    "answer_type": "is_radio",
    "optional_answer": false,
    "sub_question_type": "has_parent",
    "sub_question": [
        {
            "question_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d2f",
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d5f",
            "answer": "Bank"
        },
        {
            "question_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d45",
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d60",
            "answer": "SMB (<100)"
        }
    ],
    "answers": [
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d61",
            "answer": "answer 1"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d62",
            "answer": "answer2"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d63",
            "answer": "answer3"
        }
    ],
    "view": "list_view",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_delete": false,
    "draggable_list": [],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "61c1c2d7c204bb170e280d7e",
    "title": "Dependent 1",
    "question": "On previous Chosen option 1",
    "vendor_id": "61b8324040fb21d80f3e6702",
    "answer_type": "is_radio",
    "optional_answer": false,
    "sub_question_type": "has_parent",
    "sub_question": [
        {
            "question_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d45",
            "_id": "61c1c2d7c204bb170e280d7f",
            "answer": "Mid (100 - 1000)"
        },
        {
            "question_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d2f",
            "_id": "61c1c2d7c204bb170e280d80",
            "answer": "Tech"
        }
    ],
    "answers": [
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c2d7c204bb170e280d81",
            "answer": "answer 11"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c2d7c204bb170e280d82",
            "answer": "answer 22"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c2d7c204bb170e280d83",
            "answer": "answer 33"
        }
    ],
    "view": "list_view",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_delete": false,
    "draggable_list": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

**Query on the base of question_id and answer to find the required result:**

```json
{
    "obj": {
        "question_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d2f",
        "answer": "Bank"
    },
    "obj1": {
        "question_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d45",
        "answer": "SMB (<100)"
    }
}
```

Result want to acheive:

```
{
    "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d5e",
    "title": "Dependent",
    "question": "On previous Chosen option",
    "vendor_id": "61b8324040fb21d80f3e6702",
    "answer_type": "is_radio",
    "optional_answer": false,
    "sub_question_type": "has_parent",
    "sub_question": [
        {
            "question_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d2f",
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d5f",
            "answer": "Bank"
        },
        {
            "question_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d45",
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d60",
            "answer": "SMB (<100)"
        }
    ],
    "answers": [
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d61",
            "answer": "answer 1"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d62",
            "answer": "answer2"
        },
        {
            "is_rating": false,
            "is_specific_date": false,
            "_id": "61c1c24ac204bb170e280d63",
            "answer": "answer3"
        }
    ],
    "view": "list_view",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_delete": false,
    "draggable_list": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `$objectToArray` to convert the userInput to array of k-v tuples for easier processing
2. `$map` to check if the `question_id` is `$in` the `sub_question` array
3. `$match` by `$allElementsTrue`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "userInput": {
        "obj": {
          "question_id": "61c1c0efc204bb170e280d2f",
          "answer": "Bank"
        },
        "obj1": {
          "question_id": "61c1c142c204bb170e280d45",
          "answer": "SMB (<100)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "userInput": {
        "$objectToArray": "$userInput"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "userInput": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$userInput.v",
          "as": "q",
          "in": {
            $and: [
              {
                "$in": [
                  "$$q.question_id",
                  "$sub_question.question_id"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$in": [
                  "$$q.answer",
                  "$sub_question.answer"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          true,
          {
            "$allElementsTrue": [
              "$userInput"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K-CfphmXwgj) for your reference.

Comment: it's returning two objects. In my case I want only one object which matched both the obj and obj1.

Comment: @MunamRamay sorry for the mistake. Updated the answer to match on both `question_id` and `answer`